# button addEventListener does not function

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, addeventlistener

I am having issues getting a button to work. I want something to happen when I click this button:

```
<button id="pigBtn" value="click">Pig It!</button>
```

and my JS file has

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    console.log('hello'); 
    let pigBtn = document.querySelector('#pigBtn'); 
    console.log('pigged'); 
    pigBtn.addEventListener('click', function (){

    function pigIt(phrase) {
        let array = phrase.split(' '); 
        console.log('array'); 

        for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
            let pig = array[i].split(''); 
            let one = pig.shift(); 
            pig.push(one); 
            pig.push('ay'); 
            let two = pig.join(''); 

            array[i] = two; 
    }
        return array.join(' '); 

    }

  }); 

});
```

'hello' and 'pigged' show up but 'array' does not. What am I missing here?

Comment: `id="pigBtn"` vs `querySelector('#pigged')`

Comment: change let pigBtn = document.querySelector('#pigged');  to let pigBtn = document.querySelector('#pigBtn');

Comment: Use getElementById instead of querySelector for looking for an id... It's much faster.

Comment: There's quite a few things wrong with your code. For starters, the `pigIt` function is never executed because it's only defined... and never run. See [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060035/button-addeventlistener-does-not-function/45060429#45060429) for how you can fix your code!

Answer (score 0):

The button has id `pigBtn`, but you try to select an element with id `pigged`.

Try this instead:

```
let pigBtn = document.querySelector('#pigBtn');
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   console.log('hello'); 
   let pigBtn = document.querySelector('#pigBtn'); 
   console.log('pigged'); 
   pigBtn.addEventListener('click', function (){
      console.log('clicked'); 
   }); 
});
```

```html
<button id="pigBtn" value="click">Pig It!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  console.log('hello'); 
  let pigBtn = document.querySelector('#pigBtn'); 
  console.log('pigged');

  pigBtn.addEventListener('click', function (){
    console.log('clicked'); 
  }); 
});
```

The ID in your querySelector has to match the ID of the button in your HTML.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

Your `pigIt` function is never executed. You define it in your event handler, but you never run it.

I think you're going for something like this :

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var sentence = "This is the phrase I'm pigging";
  console.log('hello'); 
  let pigBtn = document.getElementById('pigBtn'); 
  let pigTxt = document.getElementById('phraseTxt'); 
  let pigPhraseTxt = document.getElementById('pigPhraseTxt'); 
  console.log('pigged'); 
  pigBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let array = pigTxt.value.split(' '); 
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let pig = array[i].split(''); 
      let one = pig.shift(); 
      pig.push(one); 
      pig.push('ay'); 
      let two = pig.join('');
      array[i] = two; 
    }
    pigPhraseTxt.value = array.join(' '); 
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display : block;
  width : 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

input:read-only {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phraseTxt" value="This is the text I'm converting to Pig Latin" />
<input type="text" id="pigPhraseTxt" readonly />
<button id="pigBtn" value="click">Pig It!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped. Now I just need to be able to input a text and click the button to convert the phrase to pig latin.

Comment: @BenC. : I modified the code to correspond to that use case :-)